# Generic method with return type <E>

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method with return type. I know its hardly of any practical use, generics with primitive data type,but I was experimenting. I cant understand, when a `primitive` data type is passed into arguments of `method 3` it is working, then  why casting is not working inside body of `method 4`

If its working for primitive data type in method 3,then why not inside method 4.

```
class Demo
{
    List<Demo> list = new ArrayList<Demo>();
    int id;
    int b[];

 public <E> List<E> showList()  //Method 1
 {
     return (<E>)list;   //This works fine
 }

 public <E> List <E> showList2(List<E> x) //Method 2
 {
   return x;             // This works fine 
 }

 public <E> E showNumber(E x)  //Method 3,called as new Demo().showNumber(2);
 {
    return x;   //works for every primitive data type
 }

 public <E> E show()    //Method 4
{
   return (E)id;    // Not working
 }
}
```

Comment: How would you relate `E` and `int`?

Comment: @Rohit Just like I casted a list of type List<Demo> to List<E>, can I cast it?

Comment: Downvoters, its a genuine question from a newbie.Thank you :)

Comment: If you notice, compiler would be giving you an unchecked cast warning there at list. That's because both `List<E>` and `List<Demo>` are `List` at runtime, due to type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

Due to type erasure, you will never know the type of E unless you either get `E`, `Foo<E>`, or `Class<E>` from `E.class` passed in. The type is not available at runtime in this case.

A cast may also become illegal, but we can't even get that far.

Passing in a boxed Integer gives a refiable argument, so you know the type must be Integer, and the boxed integer is thus returned.

Either genericize the `Demo` class so E is refiable, or make sure something that tells what E is (being refiable) is passed in, such as the `Foo<E>`, a `Class<E>` being populated with `E.class` or an example of `E` itself.